# Trouble Comparing Values From 2 Tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (Table1) that holds data I brought in from a simple text file. Each row has a RowID, and there are columns for page number and errors that start with null values, then the Data column that holds each row from the text file.

In my test data I know that RowID 2 has a company name in the Data column (roughly centered in the original text file). I need to compare that with Col01 of the Customers table to see if the company name is there. It seems like it should be a simple select, but I get zero rows unless I hard code the value from Table1.

Here is the query I have tried with no luck.

```
SELECT c.RowID, c.Col01, c.Col02 
FROM Customers c 
WHERE c.Col01 = 
    (SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(t.Data)) 
     FROM Table1 t 
     WHERE t.RowID = '2')
```

If I hard code the value from RowID 2 of Table1 I get several matches (with different addresses in Col02 and Col03). So I know there is data in Customers that matches the value in the Data column of Table1 on RowID 2.

The goal is to update the Errors column in Table1 to G for customers that are in the Customers table and B for ones that are not members/customers.

So why does the above select statement return zero rows when there are matches?

I'm using MS SQL 2008. The hard-coded version I tried was

```
SELECT c.RowID, c.Col01, c.Col02 FROM Customers c WHERE c.Col01 = 'Sunny Donuts'
```

The value in table1 has 35 or 40 spaces before Sunny and a few dozen after Donuts, so I used the LTRIM and RTRIM to get rid of that.

That returned a few rows. The customers table has these columns:

- RowID (int, not null)
- Col01 (varchar(100), null)
- Col02 (varchar(100), null)
- Col03 (varchar(100), null)
- Col04 (varchar(100), null)
- T_Status (char(1), null)

Col01 is the company name, and col02 through Col04 are for the address, city, state, and so on. Those can all be null values.

Table1 has these columns:

- RowID (int, not null)
- Page (int, null)
- Errors (varchar(5), null)
- Data (varchar(255) null)

These are both legacy tables (in use for several years). In both tables the RowID is an identity specification with a seed of 1 and an increment of 1.

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/62576).

Comment: Can you post the query that you hard coded to successfully return rows? The definition of the customers & table1 would be helpful, too. I assume you are using an Oracle database? `ROWID` is a reserved word pseudocolumn that may be giving you problems.

Comment: Thank you Acroyear. I should have included that.

Comment: I'm using MS SQL 2008. The hard-coded version I tried was

SELECT c.RowID, c.Col01, c.Col02 FROM Customers c WHERE c.Col01 = 'Sunny Donuts'

That returned a few rows. The customers table has these columns: RowID (int, not null), Col01 (varchar(100), null), Col02 (varchar(100), null), Col03 (varchar(100), null), Col04 (varchar(100), null), T_Status (char(1), null)

Col01 is the company name, and col02 through Col04 are for the address, city, state, and so on. 

Table1 has these columns: RowID (int, not null), Page (int, null), Errors (varchar(5), null) and Data (varchar(255) null).

Comment: These are both legacy tables (in use for several years). In both tables the RowID is an identity specification with a seed of 1 and an increment of 1.

Comment: Anything from `SELECT * FROM Customers c WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 t WHERE t.RowID = 2 AND c.Col01 LIKE CONCAT('%',RTRIM(LTRIM(t.Data)),'%'))`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Noah, you were right.

There were hidden characters (CR and LF) and that prevented the match. After I stripped those off of the data in table1 it solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

When I have issues with a compound SQL statement, what I usually do is to look at the results returned by portions of the statement. Therefore, I would try to see what this portion returns by itself:

```
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(t.Data)) FROM Table1 t WHERE t.RowID = '2'
```

If the result looks good, I would then look for the possibility of a sneaky invisible character by testing for the length of the returned string:

```
SELECT LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(t.Data))) FROM Table1 t WHERE t.RowID = '2'
```

If the result of the first query is 'Acme, Inc.', for example, this second query should return 10. If it does not, then there is a character in t.Data that should not be there. Just to make the comparison more visual, I would run this query:

```
SELECT LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(t.Data))), LEN('Acme, Inc.'), '"' + RTRIM(LTRIM(t.Data)) + '"'
  FROM Table1 t WHERE t.RowID = '2'
```

The third value above wraps the string around quotes to better visualise the presence of an invisible character either at the beginning or the end of the string.

If the above does not help, I would then focus on the values in column "RowID" of table "Table1". If that column is numeric, it is better to compare against the number 2, instead of '2', to avoid implicit conversions. If "RowID" is defined as alphanumeric, I would run this query to see if it has invisible characters as well:

```
SELECT LEN(t.RowID), '"' + t.RowID + '"' FROM Table1 t
```

I hope the above is of some help.

Comment: I am not sure about the why of the down vote, but the reason for posting this answer is because the person asking noted that Table1 was imported from a text file, and, in my experience, that usually causes unexpected characters to creep into the table, including invisible special characters. Even though the question is incomplete, it had enough to justify my suggestion. Also, I assumed SQL Server (as opposed to, say, Oracle), but, even if that assumption is an issue, the suggestions would still stand, even if there are syntactical differences.

Comment: Thank you Noah. I will try leaving off the single quotes around the value for RowID (an identity column that auto increments).

Comment: I just tried comparing the LEN value with the count of characters expected and they matched, but that is a good thing to add in since sometimes we get bad data coming in,

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @DG86. Since the lengths matched, I wonder if the character between "Sunny" and "Donuts" in Table1 is causing the issue. If you think it would help, I would try getting the ASCII value of that character. In the 'Sunny Donuts' example, that "space" would be the 6th character in the string; therefore, I would try `SELECT ASCII(SUBSTRING(RTRIM(LTRIM(t.Data)),6,1)) FROM Table1 t WHERE t.RowID = 2`, and, if it does not return 32, then it is not the traditional space and is the cause for the mismatch. I figure you typed a space in 'Sunny Donuts' in the hard-coded version.